# Data generating in a simulation

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, simulation

I am trying to check the Regression robustness of multiple Regression methods. I would like to investigate how outliers in the response variable(Y) OR in the explanatory variables (X) affect the regression methods.

I am doing this through simulation in R, but I am confused firstly about generating explanatory and response variables.

**Do I need to generate them independently or Not? Which one is right?**

Independently, for example as the following, where x is generated independently from y

```
p <- 5
n <- 100
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n)
y <- rnorm(n)
```

Or, they are related such as following, where x is used to generate y

```
p <- 5
n <- 100
x <- cbind(1, Rfast::matrnorm(n, p))
ber <- rnorm(p+1, 3, 1)
m <- x %*% ber
y <- rnorm(n, m, 1)
```

Comment: Are you just asking whether the X variables should be correlated?  They can be correlated or not as you like.  it might help if you say more about what you're trying to do.  Eg, what assumption of regression methods are you wondering is robust to what kind of violation? Etc.

Comment: I edited the question. It is not about correlated.

Comment: *"I am trying to check the Regression robustness of multiple Regression methods"* - what **exactly** do you mean by *"Regression robustness"* and how exactly are you going to check it ?

Comment: @RobertLong, I will perform a regression model with uncontaminated data and contaminated data. Then, I will have the mean absolute difference between the coefficients of clean data and coefficients with contaminated data. The mean, because this is a simulation where I will repeat the process many times.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. 1) What **exactly** do you mean by "Regression robustness" and 2) How **exactly** are you going to check it ?

Comment: @RobertLong, 1- I mean which regression method (I will check some of the regression methods) is more robust to outliers. Is it affected by outliers or not? 2- I will compare the mean absolute difference between the methods. The small difference will be less affected by outliers.

Comment: @RobertLong, I wish it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate your data in accordance with what you want the data-generating process to be. If you want your dependent variable to be related to your independent variables, then you need to generate it as such. If you don't want your dependent variable to be related to your independent variables, then you need to generate it as such. There is no right way to generate data, but you do have to propose a data-generating process (i.e., a population regression model), and simulate data from it in a way that mirrors it.

The data-generating process you seem to want to investigate is
$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_{1i} + \beta_2 X_{2i} + \dots + \beta_p X_{pi} + \varepsilon_i$$

If you set all the $\beta$s to $0$, this would correspond to your first block of code. If you want the $\beta$s to be drawn from a normal distribution, this would correspond to your second block. So the question for *you* is, which data-generating process are you trying to represent in your simulation?

You might ask, "Which data-generating process would allow me to study the statistical phenomena I wish to investigate?" That is a different question than the one you are asking here and one that would require you to go into detail about your specific research question.

Comment: Many thanks. My research question is which regression method is more robust when there are outliers in the response variable. The same when there outliers in the explanatory variables. Finally, when outliers in both.

Comment: By robust, I assume you mean "more accurate in estimating the relationship between the predictors and outcome," in which case you need to encode the relationship between the predictors and outcome in your data-generating process. You can encode that relationship to be 0, which is what your first code block does, but you have to know that that is what it's doing. Honestly, you can try two simulations; one with nonzero coefficients and one without. How you generate your data is completely up to you.

Comment: I will perform a regression model with uncontaminated data and contaminated data. Then, I will calculate the mean absolute difference between the coefficients of clean data and coefficients with contaminated data. The small difference will mean less affected by outliers. The mean is calculated because this is a simulation where I will repeat the process many times. Yes, I can generate both blocks, BUT I am afraid to report wrong results if I do something not right.